# Issues with an infinite loop when setting up a two dimenstial array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, datagrid

Im trying to setup a two dimensional array of pointers but, i'm having issues actually allocating the memory. Whenever I try to write values to the array im getting access writing location error.

Grid.h

```
class Grid 
{
public:
    Grid();

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int row;
    int col;
    Grid*** array2D;
    
};
```

Grid.cpp

```
Grid::Grid()
{
    row = 32;
    col = 30;

     // Allocate memory to point to.
    array2D = new Grid**[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        array2D[i] = new Grid*[col];
        }


    for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++)
        {
            array2D[i][j]->x=6;
            array2D[i][j]->y =5;
            
        }
    }
```

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000C1CC8 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCE29.

Exception thrown at 0x000C1CC8 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCE29.
```

Comment: Why do you need an array of *pointers* to `Grid` objects? Are your `Grid` objects stored elsewhere in memory? If not, why not use an array of *actual* `Grid` objects instead? You are allocating the array itself fine (though `std::vector` would be better to use than `new[]`), but you are not assigning the `Grid*` elements to actually point anywhere, which is why the code is crashing. Also, your 2nd set of loops are going out of bounds of the array dimensions, use `<` instead of `<=` .

Comment: It looks like you've create rows and columns but not `Grid`s. You need another loop in this first one which iterates over columns and makes them. There is another problem though, that the `Grid` contains an array of itself. I don't entirely get the conception but it looks like an infinite recursion.

Comment: @NO_NAME Good point about the potential infinite recursion, I missed that.

Comment: Using `**p` to access rows and columns in an array was common back around 1985 when memory access was faster than calculating offsets in a single array but has not been efficient for the last 3 decades or more. Is this perhaps some sort of classroom problem to learn about pointers?

Comment: Btw, I would really discourage from managing the memory at such a low level unless the point this program is to learn specifically that. You should use some higher level constructs like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector` which make mistakes harder to make and remember for you to free the memory. An equivalent of your array would be something like `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Grid>>>` (depending of what you really want to do). This may look scary but is actually quite easy to use.

Comment: Yeah im trying to do a 2D array of an 30x32 grid. Im a bit confused though how would it be an infinite recursion and aren't I already creating the columns.

Comment: @Jay You create columns of your array but not elements of columns (cells).

Comment: @NO_NAME yeah i know std would be easier but im trying to implement it without it.

Comment: @Jay The recursion is because an object of `Grid` contains an array of object of `Grid` and each of them contains an array of objects of `Grid`... So unless you have some clever plan how to prevent geometric growth of that, you have an infinite recursion in memory.

Comment: If you just need an array of constant size, there is no need for dynamic allocation of memory. This isn't Java. You just write `Grid array2D[32][30];` and call it a day.

Comment: @Jay , I updated my answer and it works now. please take a look. Please let me know if there was any question. I also appreciate up_votes and acceptance of the answer!

Comment: @Jay , could you please change the title of your question and possibly edit it  a little bit. I think it is a very good question about how to avoid an infinite loop when constructing an object which has a pointer to itself as a member. I could edit it my self but the question is originally yours!

Answer (score 0):

In the presented code, memory has been allocated for `Grid***` and `Grid**` but not for `Grid*` also the grid itself has never been initialized. So at the last level, pointer `array[x][y]` holds a meaningless value which possibly points to some where irrelevant, so the `Access violation` errors!

you should first allocate and possibly initialize the last level pointers like this:

```
array2D[i][j] = new Grid;
```

And only then try to access its elements like:

```
array2D[i][j]->x=6;
array2D[i][j]->y =5;
```

Also don't forget to correct :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
```

Another solution is to simply delete one `*` from the code and put a default constructor in order to avoid **construction loop**, like below:
Grid.h

```
class Grid
{
public:
    Grid() = default;
    Grid(int);

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int row;
    int col;
    Grid** array2D;
};
```

Grid.cpp

```
Grid::Grid(int)
{
    row = 32;
    col = 30;
    x=0;
    y=0;

     // Allocate memory to point to.
    array2D = new Grid*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        array2D[i] = new Grid[col];
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            (array2D[i][j]).x=6;
            (array2D[i][j]).y =5;
       }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
int main()
{
    Grid grid(0);
    std::cout<<"the end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah the problem that im still having is the recursive loop because if I were to allocate array2D[i][j]= new Grid; it would loop back to the first for loop.

Comment: Why should it get back to there?
simply change it to
```
    for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++)
        {
            array2D[i][j] = new Grid;
            array2D[i][j]->x=6;
            array2D[i][j]->y =5;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: AND BTW why not ```Grid** array2D;``` instead of ```Grid*** array2D;``` ?
Then you won't even need to allocate memory for new Grid at the last level!

Comment: i orignally had it has Grid ** array2D but, that again still leads to the recursive problem here.   array2D = new Grid * [row];
                   for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
  array2D[i] = new Grid[col];
 }

Comment: @Jay could you at least explain what are you trying to achieve? I do not understand how this could lead to infinite loop! are you trying to make a linked node or some thing?

Comment: trying to do a 30 by 32 grid. The Grid class contains a x and y value.  so for example at [0][2] i want to store x and y.

Comment: @Jay , I am sorry. I understood what was the problem and updated my answer! I tested it and it works without the construction loop